# Theming a view of comments

Tags: comments, theming

I have a view which creates a block of comments.  I have a comment.tpl.php in my theme folder which I use to theme the comments on the node.

To theme the view, I need a variant of comment.tpl.php and have tried the following:

comment-view.tpl.php
comment-views.tpl.php
comment-view--name-of-view.tpl.php
comment-view-name-of-view.tpl.php

After cache clearing each option the template is still not picked up.

How can I theme this view please?  By the way I am using the [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega) theme.

Comment: what version of views are you running? have you explored `Theme:Information` that is available for each view? You are probably interested in the field content template file. just a guess there.

Comment: Using views 3, the templates in theme:information do not contain the variables in comment.tpl.php.  That is why i need to override comment.tpl.php

Comment: any reason for voting this down or do you not really have a reason?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no built-in support to override comment.tpl.php on a per-view basis (if it's not in theme:information then that's true). You'll need to implement the [theme hook suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) yourself

Comment: Hi @Clive, thanks a lot for the advice, sounds right - but what does this actually mean, could you explain a little more please?  I need to access the variables in comment.tpl.php but in a template made just for the view.  THanks

Comment: I don't have time to look into it too deeply right now, but basically you'll be implementing `hook_preprocess_comment()` at the theme/module layer, trying to find some sort of reference to the `$view` object inside the `$vars` array that's passed in, and adding something like: `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'comment__' . str_replace('-', '_', $view->name);`. After a cache flush the corresponding template file should work (e.g. `comment--name-of-view.tpl.php`)

Comment: +1 for clive. i was actually just thinking the same thing for this to be done in preprocess

Comment: I've added an answer to this, thanks a lot @clive for your help.  Not sure if it's best practice though?

Comment: @rix That's absolutely spot on :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, i just had a breakthrough today in terms of theming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I came up with some sort of solution, thanks to @clive.

```
function hook_preprocess_comment(&$vars){
    if (isset($vars['view'])) { 
        $view = $vars['view'];

            if ($view->name == "my_view_name"){
            $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'comment__' . str_replace('-', '_', $view->name);
    }   
  }   
}
```

I tried to do $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] but those templates were never picked up.  Is it ok to directly set theme_hook_suggestion.

Really hope this helps someone else out there..

Answer (score 0):

When in the views UI, under 'advanced' on the right hand side, down the bottom you will see 'Theme' with a link next to it saying 'information' (under the 'Other' heading). Click the information link to see many template file name suggestions.

Comment: As stated, I need to override comment.tpl.php as it contains the variables needed for theming.